# How using ssh-keygen generate public key that would have ---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ---- at the top?

Tags: azure, powershell, ssh, public-key-encryption, ssh-keygen

I am using PowerShell and generate keys with the following command

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com" -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`

Keys get generated however public key is a single line and does not have `---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----` at the top and `---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----` at the end which are required when starting Azure instance with SSH public key admin account.

I could just add those lines manually I guess, but I have a feeling since key generation is a commonly done thing, there should be a way to do it via command line.

**How using ssh-keygen generate a public key that would have  ---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----  at the top?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out myself

I had to add `-e` (export) option

Full command looks following:

`ssh-keygen -b 2048 -C "email@gmail.com" -f $HOME/.ssh/id -e`

Comment: To clarify, after running `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` you have to run `ssh-keygen -b 2048 -C "email@gmail.com" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -e`